# Search video with vimeo Api using javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, vimeo-api

I want to use the new vimeo api to fetch videos based on a query, but I getting a 401 Authorization Required with this message "error": "A valid user token must be passed."

I'm using this code :

```
var urlX = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=elvis&client_id='+VIMEO_API_KEY;

$.getJSON(urlX, function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

So obviously I have an authentication problem. 
As client_id I'm using my "Client Identifier" from my app created in Vimeo's dashboard. 
The error I keep getting mention "user token", do I have to generate one via Vimeo's dashboard or via php ?
I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Where did you find the information about client_id? That's no longer valid, and I would like to remove any reference to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

client_id through the querystring is not a valid method of making API calls against the Vimeo API.

First you must request an access token either through the oauth2 redirect worfklow: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication, or by generating it on your app page.

Second you must provide that access token with your api request either through the Authorization header:

`Authorization: bearer <your_token>`

or the querystring

`https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=elvis&access_token=<your token>`.

The authorization header is more secure, and will continue to work indefinitely. Some changes will be made soon to the querystring form which could cause problems with your application.

Comment: God, thanks a lot. Could you please put the sample querystring that you provided in this answer to somewhere in the API documentation page?

Comment: The querystring format is not recommended, and will change in the future. Future versions will only allow access tokens with the "public" scope, nothing more.

Comment: what does "bearer" mean in the Authorization header?

Comment: It's how the bearer token RFC wants you to use the authorization header. The RFC is here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750

Comment: How to make authentication api request to get access token...there are two ways one is unauthenticated tokens and other is authenticated tokens.

Which api should use ?..i used authenticated token.but throws errors

https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=xxxxxx&state=xxxxx .

what is the value to be inserted in state.

can any one please help me.

i am using Angular JS calling the api.